# How to decide between using a custom Relationship and using a custom Contact Reference field?

Tags: custom-fields, relationships, architecture

This is admittedly open-ended any may just depend too much on use-case. I am looking for advice on when it is preferable to create a custom **Contact Reference** field instead of just creating a custom relationship.

If you have an example of a situation where you chose one over the other, that would be helpful.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind - maintaining relationships can put a burden on the user/administrator.  For example, setting up for spouses, the way the system is designed, encourages (does not require) a household + spouse A + Spouse B.  I've found there is a lot of overhead / training / automation to manage the household.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Relationships

- Can be used to give permissions between contacts
- Have a start & end date
- Can attach notes & additional custom data
- Can be displayed as advanced search results

### Custom contact reference fields

- Can be added to a profile form
- Can be displayed in its own tab or section of the contact summary page
- Customizable autocomplete filters for limiting which contacts are selectable

### Both

- Can be added to a (drupal) webform
- Are searchable via advanced search
- Could be the basis of a smart group
- Can be used in a report (although custom fields are in all reports whereas relationships are only in certain reports)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I default toward relationships, but might use a custom reference field in these situations:

- I need to export multiple people with the same relationship.  For instance, if Andy and Beth both have a "Mentor of" relationship to Johnny, you can't export Johnny's record showing both mentors.  So I'll make two contact reference fields.
- You need to create a form where a site visitor needs to specify an existing contact.  For instance, if new members must be referred by existing members, you may want them to be able to submit a profile that indicates who the referring member is.  If you use Webform-CiviCRM Integration, I think you can do this with a relationship, but otherwise, you need a contact reference field.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm keeping this open for a while to see what others have to share.